# Windows Authentication Between React and ASP.NET Back-end

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I have a multi-tier application which is using 2 NET Core ASP.NET tiers.

- Tier 01

  - React JS hosted via ASP.NET Core
- Tier 02

  - Back-end HTTP rest

The Tier 01 is using NTLM, so when the User open the Browser, ASP.NET Core loads the React SPA and from ASP.NET Core I can get the IPrincipal of the current Windows User. The Back-end, unfortunately, is always running in the context of the App Pool service account.

In this scenario, what would be the correct way, from React, to call the Back-end using the Windows Account which is running the application? Is there a way to generate a Token, like OAuth, in the Front-end NET Core host and then pass it to the Back-end?

**Note**

I do have an architectural requirement, I can't use Username and Password, I can't use Basic Authentication. The Front-end must open using NTLM and display the current Windows Account (*this part is working*)

Comment: Are your users declared in Azure Active Directory? Or a locally deployed Active Directory?

Comment: Company AD, we are not using Azure in this scenario

Comment: @Raffaeu, I have a same scenario wherein I have a react app(in windows env) and spring boot REST APIs for back-end, I just want that whenever user opens react app I want to get the username of logged in system user(always windows) in my back-end for authentication. Could you please suggest something?

Comment: In Spring the easiest is to use a Spring action to host your React so it will force windows authentication before loading React client app
To authenticate with Windows on Spring you can easily use Waffle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the approach mentioned in below link.
In tier 01, create an API endpoint that requires Windows Authentication. Get user info from the identity and generate a token.

[Use Windows Authentication with OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27217424/use-windows-authentication-with-oauth-2-0)

For token generation, let's use IdentityServer.
[Generate access token with IdentityServer4 without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172221/generate-access-token-with-identityserver4-without-password)

Comment: Nice, I didn't think about Identity Server. So that was my point, if I can get a Token also from Windows Authentication